# Android Studio Mac does not see USB device

Tags: macos, usb, android, android-studio, macos-mojave

When i try to run my project on a physical Android device (Huawei P30), android studio fails to see it. I've tried the common troubleshooting methods,like killing adb `adb kill-server
adb devices` , downloading SDK tools, no change.

The problem is not in the cable, since the OS is able to see it, but ADB cannot connect to it. Restarting the ADB server did not work.

I also tried reinstalling android studio, since the first time i installed it, due to some privacy settings it could not install HAXM. i tried `brew cask install intel-haxm`
, but nothing changed.

What else can i try to make Android Studio see my device on a mac Mojave?

Comment: The place for Android questions is [android.se].